# amchart stock chart group by hour of the day / day of the week/week of the month

Tags: amcharts

Want to draw a chart with chart ScrollBar like this:

http://www.amcharts.com/demos/drawing-trend-lines/#theme-none

but need to group result not only by day but also  by hour of the day, day of the week, week of the month, day of the month and so on.

documentation suggest to use groupToPeriod  but that's only for fit for this purpose and seems it is not possible to achieve the result..

can suggest the solution.. or any workaround?

Thanks

Joe

Comment: Sorry, i don't get your question... What's the problem with groupToPeriod? What have you tried already? Can you show the data you want to group? And what's the matter with the scrollbar?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.
I have a TimeStamp (datetime2) value and some other parameters of the access of a webpage. example:
2015-02-12 20:48:46.5462187,45241,BKJFF,42
......
2015-02-13 01:11:17.2454184|12845,LKITA,57
.....
2015-02-13 01:56:12.4751247|34269,HGLDA,11

I want to group data by hour of the day in way to have, regardless of the number of logs, 24 bars, one for each  hour of the day, each indicating how many access has been made at that hour:
In our example: bar 20 with value 1 and bar 01 with value 2 and all other bars with value 0.
groupToPeriod groups in different way

Comment: So you want the sum for each hour / day / week / month, depending on the range of your view?

Comment: yes, right as you can see here:
[link](https://mega.co.nz/#!HtgHXbgS!npEmONVYln-7OdQWg6fUBTN6DPj79qdry6cDr9HL9V4)
but plus scroll bar: in this case scrollbar will not limit the number fo rows to show (that remains 24 or 7) but the range of day from which calculate the n. of views.

tks
Joe

Comment: Do you mind having multiple datasets? I'm not aware of any amcharts function that will fit your needs, but i think it shouldn't be difficult to make a manual mock-up for this.

Comment: No, have 1 single dataset, but the logs of last week are different from logs of 3 weeks ago: now we use google charts and have several buttons for 1 week/2 weeks/1 month/3months.. selection and every button queries the database with appropriate time frame: target is to achieve same (or better) result with scroll bar that will allow to select an arbitrary time frame. 
On server side for each day will extract the list of access splitted by hour:
{"date":"08-02",
"00":49,
"01":32,
"02":17,
"03":9,
"04":5,
"05":24,
"06":47,
"07":82,
"08":146,
"09":219,
"10":416,
"11":684,
"12":914,
and so on

Comment: Take a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/pc8p3/embedded/result,js,html,css/). What i meant with multiple Datasets was, that you could change your Dataset in the background.

Comment: Hi again.
Well this is not what I meant but I think that listening to the scrollbar to show different sets of data or different "rows" can be the solution.
pls see here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JanR/fLn089cr/)
thks
Joe

Comment: So your idea with hiding each graph would work. ([Docs](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCoordinateChart#hideGraph)) But i wonder, whats wrong with the multiple datasets. I think switching the dataset should has better performance, as the graph don't "knows" about all the other data in this moment.